# I am renewing my passport but confused for Non ECR Category

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, passport-renewals, ecr

The question is "Is the applicant eligible for the Non-ECR category?"

I'm renewing mine and my sister's passport and right now I'm studying for a diploma (2nd year). My sister is in 10th standard right now.

Comment: I am assuming you are applying for Indian Passport? Please check the documentation provided on the website itself.http://www.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/onlineHtml/NonEcrDocuments.html

Comment: @ItiTyagi you would be welcome to make a summary of what the site says in an answer and then include the official link. I think it would be well received.

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand if your request lies in ECR or Non-ECR, it is important to understand what ECR means. "ECR" stands for Emigration Check Required. In order to stand in a category where you do not require Emigration Check, you need to show any of the following below :

[image]
[image]

**Conclusion** : If you hold any of the above mentioned documents, you need to chose "Non ECR" Category checkbox while filling the form.

[image]